# iText diacritic characters such as D̂, M̂ and so on not displayed correctly on PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm having a problem with iText when I'm trying to create a PDF that contains characters like the ones in the title. 
What happens is that the accent circonflexe does not sit properly above the letter but rather right next to it or (depending on what font I use) somewhat "merged" into it (see screenshot below where I used FreeSans).

[image: FreeSans]

I know that all the characters that have this problem are "composite" characters. What I mean by this is that they are composed of two unicode characters. For example the "D̂" is represented as "\u0044\u0302" whereas all the usual characters are of course represented as "\uXXXX".
So I'm pretty sure that it has to do with this. 
For example an "Ê" which has a normal  unicode representation is displayed just fine.

Here is a tiny code snippet that hopefully contains everything you need to know:

```
String TEXT = "\u0044\u0302 \u004A\u030C \u004C\u0302 \u004D\u0302 \u004E\u0302 \u0064\u0302 \u006C\u0302 \u006D\u0302 \u006E\u0302";//D̂ J̌ L̂ M̂ N̂ d̂ l̂ m̂ n̂
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("FreeSans.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
document.add(new Paragraph(TEXT, font));
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `TEXT = java.text.Normalizer.normalize(TEXT, Normalizer.Form.NFC);` help? (Combined letters exist?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use iText 7 with the module pdfCalligraph. This kind of composing requires access to the OTF tables to align correctly the chars depending on size, height, etc.

For more info on [pdfCalligraph](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph), see the [chapter 2 of the "iText 7: building blocks"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) tutorial (please scroll towards the end of the chapter) to find out how it works. You can get a free trial version of pdfCalligraph [here](http://pages.itextpdf.com/iText-7-Free-Trial-Landing-Page-1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Does this mean that it's *definitely not* possible to get these characters to be displayed correctly without iText 7 (and pdfCalligraph)?

Comment: That's correct. The interpretation of the OTF typographical tables is essential to place the diacritical in the right place, otherwise what you get is a general placement that will only look good by accident.

Comment: Okay thanks, at least now I know that it cannot be done this way.