# How to use opentype features in itext 7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I use fontlab studio, I create ligatures in it using OpenType, Is it possible to use **ligatures** in itext 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to apply OpenType features on text written with iText7, including ligatures, but it requires *pdfCalligraph* - an iText7 addon.

See also this answer [iText diacritic characters such as D̂, M̂ and so on not displayed correctly on PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223093/itext-diacritic-characters-such-as-d%CC%82-m%CC%82-and-so-on-not-displayed-correctly-on-p) and specifically next paragraph:

> For more info on [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph), see the [chapter 2 of the "iText 7: building blocks"](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) tutorial (please scroll towards the end of the chapter) to find out how it works. You can get a free trial version of pdfCalligraph [here](http://pages.itextpdf.com/iText-7-Free-Trial-Landing-Page-1.html).

When you have pdfCalligraph you'll have to enable ligatures explicitly, because they are considered an optional feature. You can use next snippet of code as an example:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT_PATH, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
document.setProperty(Property.FONT, font);

String text1 = "Testing ligatures feature in layout (off): Fff akt ikto!";
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text1);
document.add(p);

String text2 = "Testing ligatures feature in layout (on): Fff akt ikto!\nAnd also kerning: AWAWAWA";
Paragraph pLiga = new Paragraph(text2);
pLiga.setProperty(Property.TYPOGRAPHY_CONFIG, new TypographyConfigurator()
        .addFeatureConfig(
                new LatinScriptConfig()
                        .setLigaturesApplying(true)
                        .setKerningFeature(true)
        ));
document.add(pLiga);

document.close();
```

Example output:
[image: Image showing effect of applying opentype features via pdfCalligraph]

Comment: It does not work. That's what it looks like on the Word:[word](http://rgho.st/7bpBC5PFL/thumb.png), That's what it looks like on the Pdf in itext:[itext_pdf](http://rgho.st/88CpYxKGr/thumb.png)

Comment: I did copy / paste and added the library and license key.

Comment: Yep, I speak Russian :)
Could you share the font file? The iText library specifically expects "liga" feature to be present when `setLigaturesApplying` method is called. You can compare your font structure with `foglihtenno07` font (https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/foglihtenno07), it's the one used in example.

Comment: If your feature is called differently, you can still mark it to be used with `prependCustomFeature(String)` method in `LatinScriptConfig` class. Or, if you want it to be applied both for Latin and Cyrillic scripts, you can use this config `new StandardScriptConfig(new HashSet<Character.UnicodeScript>(Arrays.asList(Character.UnicodeScript.LATIN, Character.UnicodeScript.CYRILLIC)))` instead of the `LatinScriptConfig`.

Comment: Thank you, [font](http://rgho.st/6zcLRpwxB) .[image Liba](http://rgho.st/6SdHSMrpV) Спасибо)